# как добавить красный цвет SVG из url () в CSS

Tags: html, css, svg

Пытался кратко залить красный цвет. Результат нет.

```
.icon {
   fill: red;
   background: url("https://daks2k3a4ib2z.cloudfront.net/57a245dbf22749a73c2095bc/57ade47d1fd32dc352ace5b5_5774494a52b43cbe655759a1_home.svg");
}
```

Comment: а вообще то не хватает возможность?

Comment: Осмелюсь предположить, что если постараться и настроить передающую svg сторону, так чтобы при изменении части URL - запроса менялся цвет. Это реально : svg возможно редактировать как текстовый файл. Да, всё зависит от сложности самой картинки... но я бы думал бы в этом направлении

Comment: смотрите в строну svg mask : https://jsfiddle.net/Geyan/7nsajzdv/  смотрите примеры как это работает

Comment: вот к примеру я mask применил к Gif анимации : http://codepen.io/Geyan/pen/YGdBqY?editors=110

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Чтобы изменять SVG через CSS весь код из SVG файла должен быть у вас на странице в DOM дереве. Тогда вы сможете изменять стили с помощью CSS селекторов